# ORACLE: Insert multiple records based on a single column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Based on a column's value (`COLUMN_NAME`) in Table_1 I want to insert 3 new records into Table_2.
What's the best way of doing it? I have tried it as below but I don't want to use three queries using `UNION ALL`

```
SQL> DROP TABLE TABLE_2
Table dropped.
SQL> CREATE TABLE TABLE_2(EMP_ID VARCHAR2(10),VALUE VARCHAR2(10))
Table created.
SQL> TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_2
Table truncated.
SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_2
(EMP_ID,VALUE)
WITH TABLE_1 as 
(
    SELECT '111' AS EMP_ID,'COL1' COLUMN_NAME FROM DUAL
)
SELECT EMP_ID,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1' THEN 'RICK' END AS VALUE  
FROM TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_ID,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1' THEN 'TOM' END AS VALUE  
FROM TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_ID,CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1' THEN 'ADAM' END AS VALUE  
FROM TABLE_1
COMMIT
3 rows created.
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE_2

EMP_ID     VALUE     
---------- ----------
111        RICK      
111        TOM       
111        ADAM      

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: What's wrong with `union all`?

Comment: The number of Union alls could vary sometimes. Im ok if this the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`INSERT ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423):

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO TABLE_2(EMP_ID,VALUE) VALUES (EMP_ID, 'Rick')
  INTO TABLE_2(EMP_ID,VALUE) VALUES (EMP_ID, 'Tom')
  INTO TABLE_2(EMP_ID,VALUE) VALUES (EMP_ID, 'Adam')
SELECT '111' AS EMP_ID,'COL1' COLUMN_NAME FROM DUAL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02a8009538d29e1f8d8b9a0cc9f0006e)**

Comment: @1pluszara . . . Although this is  clever way to address the issue, I don't see any advantage of this over using `UNION ALL`.